# Centering border-right vertically with height and line-height doesn't work

Tags: html, css, centering

There is this rule "when you do a line-height equal to your parent element's height - you center the text." Right ? And it works for letters LT and EN in my code. I set the height of ul 40px and line-height of li to 40px. And everything is beautiful.
But it doesnt work with border right. I need it to be as a 17px seperator between languages buttons in the center, but currently it is on top like so : http://jsfiddle.net/TomasRR/nxf5ey2a/

```
<ul class="lang">
    <li class="lt">
        <a href="#">LT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="en">
        <a href="#">EN</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.lang {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    list-style:none;
}
ul.lang li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
}
ul.lang li:first-child {
    height: 17px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
ul.lang li:last-child {
    padding-left: 6px;
}
ul.lang li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line-height` should be set to `ul` and reset to normal to `li`.

For `li` to follow `line-height`, they must: **not float** and be formatted as an inline boxe (either `inline-block` or `inline-table`) wich triggers a proper layout.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxf5ey2a/1/)

```
 ul.lang {
     float: left;
     height: 40px;
     list-style:none;
     background:orange;
     line-height: 40px;
     padding:0 5px
 }
 ul.lang li {
     display:inline-block;/*no float*/
     vertical-align:middle;/* align from baseline/line-height of parent or highest box aside */ 
     line-height:1.2em;/* reset line-height to regular value */
 }
 ul.lang li:first-child {
     padding-right: 6px;
     border-right: 1px solid black;
 }
 ul.lang li:last-child {
     padding-left: 6px;
 }
 ul.lang li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The vertical-alignment only works on inline elements.

Therefor, don't float the list-items, instead display them inline:

```
ul.lang li {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nxf5ey2a/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the padding and the border to the `<a>`, it should work:

```
ul.lang li:first-child a {
  padding-right: 6px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.lang li:first-child {
    height: 17px;
}
```

How about you change that to the correct `40px` if you want it to exactly fit inside its 40px high parent?

[That fixes it](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/nxf5ey2a/3/).

Comment: oh no, I need it to be 17px, like in psd, but thanks ;]

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display:inline
```

property in place of

```
float:left
```

See this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/unicode/g846u1nv/